# Unable to access css file from html templates

Tags: python, html, css, django, static

I can load my HTML templates but can't load css.  When I view the source code in my browser and access the css file from there it shows the error `"Page not found (404)"   'css\index.css' could not be found`

I have tried all the things from doc but I don't know what I'm missing. Does anyone know what changes I need to make so that the css loads properly?

Here are relevant files:

`settings.py`

```
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

TEMPLATES_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'parking',

        'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR, ],


STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

`app urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index)
]
```

`urls.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('parking.urls'))
]

urlpatterns +=staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

this is my HTML file

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <html class="nojs html css_verticalspacer" lang="en-US">
     <head>

      <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>

 <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/site_global.css' %}"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/master_a-master.css' %}"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/index.css' %}" id="pagesheet"/>
  <!-- IE-only CSS -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/nomq_preview_master_a-master.css' %}"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/nomq_index.css' %}" id="nomq_pagesheet"/>
  <![endif]-->
  <!-- Other scripts -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
   var __adobewebfontsappname__ = "muse";
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show us your html file?

Comment: the one thing that stands out to me is that you're doing `urlpatterns +=staticfiles_urlpatterns()` (without having previously defined `urlpatterns`) and then *resetting* `urlpatterns` to something else entirely...

Comment: There are not enough ]'s in your source.

Comment: Set your STATIC_ROOT and collect the static files with python manage.py collectstatic

Comment: i have edit the html